# JQuery animation not working on anchor tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, anchor, jquery-easing

I am using the easing plugin to 'shake' my anchor tag when a user hovers with the mouse.  It works if I attach it to any element other than the `<a>` tag.  I also tried attaching the behavior to the preceding `<li>` but it didn't work there either.  I'm a right noob with JQuery;  I figured it must be something specifically to do with anchor tags, but I couldn't find anything with a quick Google search.  Perhaps I'm overlooking something?  Here is my code below:

```
          <section id="content">
              <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="selected">Home</li>
                        <li style="margin-left:35px;"><a href="about_alabama_bunker.html" title="Learn about Alabama Bunker" class="shake">About</a></li>
                        <li style="margin-left:5px;"><a href="services_offered.html" title="Services offered by Alabama Bunker" class="shake">Services</a></li>
                        <li style="margin-left:5px;"><a href="security_bunker_products.html" title="Product catalog" class="shake">Products</a></li>
                        <li style="margin-left:25px;"><a href="contact_alabama_bunker.html" title="Get in touch with our sales staff for inquiries, comments or suggestions" class="shake">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
              </nav>

          </section>
```

and my JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.shake').hover(function(event) {
    $(this)
        .css(
            {'color': 'ff0000' }, {
                duration: 'slow',
                easing: 'easeOutBounce'
            })
        .animate(
            { left: 25 }, {
                duration: 'fast',
                easing: 'easeOutBounce'
            })
        .animate(
            { left: 0 }, {
                duration: 'fast',
                easing: 'easeOutBounce'
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

I removed the first animation for the color change.  I have tried moving the class into the `<nav>` and the `<ul>` element respectively.  I have also made sure the call to the selector is to `$(.shake)` instead of `$(a.shake)`.  No workee in any circumstance.

Comment: You tried to add `event.preventDefault();` at the top or bottom of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css, have you attribute `position: relative` or `position: absolute` ?

```
nav ul li a.shake {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    }


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.shake').hover(function(event) {
        $(this)
            .animate(
                { left: 200 }, {
                    duration: 'slow',
                    easing: 'easeOutBounce'
                })
            .animate(
                { left: 0 }, {
                    duration: 'slow',
                    easing: 'easeOutBounce'
                });
    });
});
  </script>
```

Without adding `position` attribute it won't work also with `event.preventDefault()`.

Also i hope that you have in your `<head>` tag

```
<script src="yourPath/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It's necessary for work.

---

So edit your code like this:

```
<section id="content">
              <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a style="position: relative; margin-left:35px;" href="about_alabama_bunker.html" title="Learn about Alabama Bunker" class="shake">About</a></li>
                        <li><a style="position: relative; margin-left:5px;" href="services_offered.html" title="Services offered by Alabama Bunker" class="shake">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a style="position: relative; margin-left:5px;" href="security_bunker_products.html" title="Product catalog" class="shake">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a style="position: relative; margin-left:25px;" href="contact_alabama_bunker.html" title="Get in touch with our sales staff for inquiries, comments or suggestions" class="shake">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
              </nav>
          </section>
```

I tested it and it works!

Comment: That did it.  You've saved me hours of hair-pulling.  I suppose an element must either have its dimensions defined or hasLayout has to be triggered by a position:xxx declaration?

Comment: each element that you have `animate` with easing must have declared property `position`

Comment: Is this true for any animate call or only animate with easing?